# route the url in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, maproute

I have this path

**In view**

```
  <img src="PhotoDisplay.ashx?photoid=12&size=medium" alt="Image with no resize"/>
```

I want to route the source url to an action . I must need to use this url format because i am rebuilding a site .so i want to make all the links alive in new site too.
In global.asax i added the rout like shown below

```
routes.MapRoute(
          "PhotoDisplay", "PhotoDisplay.ashx?photoid={photoID}&size={size}",
          new { controller = "Images", action = "PhotoDisplay", photoid= "",size="" }
      );
```

But its giving error while compiling .How can i map route for that kind of url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string parameters should not be defined in a route. Try like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PhotoDisplay", 
    "PhotoDisplay.ashx",
    new { controller = "Images", action = "PhotoDisplay" }
);
```

and the controller action:

```
public ActionResult PhotoDisplay(string photoid, string size)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @NullPointer, `not working` is my favorite problem description. It is so detailed and explicit that I really don't know how could you do such a great and detailed description. So back to the point: what is not working? Are you getting an exception? How does your full route definitions look like? What url are you testing? What controllers have you defined? In which web server you are testing? Once you answer those questions we could understand what's going on. Because the code I have shown here worked perfectly fine for me when I created a new application and ran in the built-in server.

Comment: My mistake. Next time i will try to explain more.  :( sorry .Its working fine .There was a mistake in url i given . Thanks for your answer .This is not first time you giving me answers .Thanks  again